# Symfony 4: append missing USE statement to error environment log

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have recently moved to Symfony 4 from Silex.

Generally speaking, everything works great!

However, in one specific case, I see 50x errors while the error log is empty. This happens with the following error:

> (1/1) InvalidArgumentException
>   Cannot determine controller argument for "App\Controller\IndexController::s()": the $UserPhotoDownloaderService argument is type-hinted with the non-existent class or interface: "App\Controller\UserPhotoDownloaderService". Did you forget to add a use statement?

As mentioned in the error, I forgot to add a use statement. I see this error via webpage but I would like to see it in my `{env}.log` as well (**All other errors are being appended to `{env}.log`**

You can reproduce this error by using the following controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
class IndexController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index_name")
     *  
     */
    public function index() {
        return new Response('Response');
    }
    /**
     * @param UserPhotoDownloaderService $UserPhotoDownloaderService
     */
    public function s(UserPhotoDownloaderService $UserPhotoDownloaderService) {
      //Should throw an error - and log it to env.log
    }
}
```

Full error from webpage: 
[image]

Is there a way to add this error to the `{env}.log` (**preferably without a custom handler**)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a custom handler, but you will have to create an event listener to the event `onKernelException` and pass it the Logger in the constructor. Then you will receive the exception in the event. You extract it, and you log it.

UPDATE:

By looking at your stack trace again, your error happens at compile time, meaning, when the container class is being built. AFAIK, there's no way to hook into the error handling process at compile level. Your app hasn't even booted yet when this error happens. So hooking into the `onKernelException` event won't help you. This is why the error is not logged: you don't have any services available at this point.

So, why would you like to log an error of this nature? An error like this does not belong to the reponse/request cycle. In fact, a simple `bin/console` would trigger this error as well.

Comment: Fair enough. Is there a reason why this error is not being logged by default while other are?

Comment: Sorry, my first answer was totally wrong. Now that I see your stack trace again, I realized the error. Updating.

Comment: > So, why would you like to log an error of this nature? An error like this does not belong to the reponse/request cycle. In fact, a simple bin/console would trigger this error as well. 

True. But unfortunately, in some rare occasions this will go to production by accident. Without Symfony, you will naturally see this in `php_error.log` which is what I am looking for.